# adding to and changing a parameter in bash

Tags: bash, parameters, editing

Is there a way to take a parameter regardless of what it is and change it to a more specific output.

I'm trying to find a way that I can change `M26 (or M27, M28, L26, L27....)` to `M0000026.00` so later on in the script I can call on the new form of the parameter

I know i could do something like:

```
./test.sh M26

if [ "$1" = M26 ]

   then

   set -- "M0000026.00" "${@:1}"

fi
```

`some function` to call `$1` in file string `/..../.../.../$1/.../..`

but I'm looking more for  a generic way so I don't have to input all the possible `if` statements for every 3 character parameter I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of `bash` supports associative arrays, you can do something like this:

```
# Declare an associative array to contain your argument mappings
declare -A map=( [M26]="M0000026.00" [M27]="whatever" ["param with spaces"]="foo" )

# Declare a regular array to hold your remapped args
args=()

# Loop through the shell parameters and remap them into args()
while (( $# )); do
   # If "$1" exists as a key in map, then use the mapped value.
   # Otherwise, just use "$1"
   args+=( "${map["$1"]-$1}" )
   shift
done

# At this point, you can either just use the args array directly and ignore
# $1, $2, etc. 
# Or you can use set to reassign $1, $2, etc from args, like so:
set -- "${args[@]}"
```

Also, you don't have to declare `map` on a single line as I did. For maintainability (especially if you have lots of mappings), you can do it like this:

```
declare -A map=()
map["M26"]="M0000026.00"
map["M27"]="whatever"
...
map["Z99"]="foo bar"
```

Comment: Yes my bash was able to support this method, and this is a lot easier to go back in and update as more file paths are added instead of adding if/fi statements! -Thanks